# Opening tabs using selenium based on user input

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to make a script where the program takes input of multiple URLs and then opens tabs for each of them, this is what I came up with

```
s=raw_input()
l=s.split()
t=len(l)

for elements in l:
    elements = ["https://" + elements + "" for elements in l]

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:/Users/mynam/Desktop/WB/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

for e in elements:
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.execute_script("window.open(e,'new window')")

print "Opened in new tab"
```

I get an error of e not defined, how do we pass an argument to window.open in selenium

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute new window, switch to it and open new page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os


def open_tab_page(page, page_number):
    browser.execute_script("window.open('');")
    browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[page_number])
    browser.get(page)

# initialise driver
chrome_driver = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
browser.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")

# list of pages to open
pages_list = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.youtube.com/']

page_number = 1
for page in pages_list:
    open_tab_page(page, page_number)
    page_number +=1
```

Comment: Which line do I insert the path statement of the chromedriver ? It gives me the "Chromedriver must be in the executable path" error.

Comment: It is also giving me the error that argument of type 'WebDriver' is not iterable

Comment: Also, is chromedriver and webdriver the same ?

Comment: @shawnindamnen replace `webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)` with the path to you chromedriver `webdriver.Chrome(r"C:/Users/mynam/Desktop/WB/chromedriver.exe")` then you can comment `chrome_driver = ...`